# php calculation gives a weird result for 1500000-20%

Tags: php, percentage, subtraction

May be I might be blind or silly, but look at my function:

```
function max_min_twenty($value) {
if ((int)$value == 0) {
    return "0"; 
} else {
    $percent_val = ((int)$value / 100) * 20;
    $maxvalue = (int)$value + $percent_val;
    $minvalue = (int)$value - $percent_val;
    $returnvalue = round($minvalue)."-".round($maxvalue);
    return $returnvalue;
}
}
```

Seems that this is really easy! It works like it should, but if my *$value* is 1500000 it gives me back **1,2E+6** for *$minvalue* - It does well if I choose a different number or if I change the percent to 19 or 21. Whats that?

Its running on PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the number *explicitly as an integer*? `round` returns a *float* and so I believe the default formatting is "getting confused" or "hitting an edge case" and reverts to displaying *scientific notation*. (I can't trigger the problem on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZJmVWd) - it might be specific to a particular PHP version/environment - but the symptoms fit.)

Try [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
return sprintf("%d-%d", $minvalue, $maxvalue);
```

(I removed `round` as the `%d` forces the arguments to be treated as integers; however, there might be subtle differences in the rounding rules .. I don't know.)

Comment: Well the sprintf method certainly solved the problem - THANK YOU! But still leaves the question why it only broke with 1500000 an 20%. What kind of limit could this hit? Maybe it would help me to know that too ;-)

Comment: @maisch I'm not sure - I tried to repro here http://ideone.com/ZJmVWd, but could not. It might be the case that the epsilon-delta calculation is "just high enough" to make the default rules treat it as not-an-integer. (Mantissa-exponent floating point values - like *float* - cannot exactly represent all possible integers within their range.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use number_format

```
function max_min_twenty($value) {
if ((int)$value == 0) {
    return "0"; 
} else {
    $percent_val = ((int)$value / 100) * 20;
    $maxvalue = (int)$value + $percent_val;
    $minvalue = (int)$value - $percent_val;
    $returnvalue = number_format(round($minvalue),"0","-","")."-   ".number_format(round($maxvalue),"0","-","");
    echo $returnvalue;
}
}
```

it changed scientific notation to standard form.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a bugged behavior in older versions of PHP. This was [bug #43053](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43053) that was resolved in PHP 5.3.0.

Take, for example, this code:

```
for ($i = 1000000; $i < 2000000; $i += 100000)
    echo round($i) . "--\n";
```

On PHP 5.2.6 and lower, it produces the following ([sample](http://codepad.org/Oc0UIWzs); *can't guarantee CodePad will always be on old PHP*):

```
1000000--
1100000--
1.2E+6--
1300000--
1.4E+6--
1500000--
1600000--
1.7E+6--
1800000--
1.9E+6--
```

On PHP 5.3.0 and up, though, the correct behavior can be seen:

```
1000000--
1100000--
1200000--
1300000--
1400000--
1500000--
1600000--
1700000--
1800000--
1900000--
```

This can be fixed by upgrading PHP or by avoiding `round()`, as @user2246674 suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120021/1438733).

Comment: It seems like the bug exists without round (as long as it's a *float* value). Good find :D

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks for the explication. Now I used round in the sprintf function and that works fine for me.